# Repeating Rows in custom list

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I'm trying to create a mileage reimbursement log in sharepoint13 but can't use infopath because I was told by my super that it would require licenses for all users. So the form I wanted to create is formatted something like this:

```
Emp Name_______________

Date____________________

Ceneter Num_____________
```

======================================================================================

```
From Dest______________   To Dest____________________  Mile___________________________

click to add row

Total miles_______________________
```

======================================================================================

```
trip purpose___________________________________________________________________________

comments________________________________________________________________________________

SUBMIT
```

I'm having a problem with the center section, id like the from dest, to dest, mile to repeat by clicking the add row link but I can't find much info out there to do this other than using using info path. After I create this I need to set up a workflow to email the director for approval and then once approved send email to finance dept to process form

Comment: Why do you need licenses for all users to use InfoPath? You can create browser enabled form http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=959

Comment: will the end user need an enterprise license for share point or would they be able to fill out this form and submit it via the intranet? I've created the form in info path and uploaded form as browser enabled form but i have created an additional site that i deactivated SharePoint Server Enterprise Site features and when i fill in form and submit the data isnt uploaded to library

Comment: I didn't thought about it from this point of view. Yes, infopath is enterprise feature and you will need user licenses. I guess your best way to go is to create custom asp.net form.